# Navigation tab: How to stop moving from one tab to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I click on another tab from the tab I am currently in, I want to take an input (via VBA message box). If I give yes input, another tab will be selected otherwise the current tab will remain. How can I do this?

I tried in my navigation form like this:
[image]

```
Private Sub navReports_LostFocus(cancel As Integer)
     If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to get out of here?", vbYesNo, "Change Tab") = vbNo Then
        cancel = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happened - error message, wrong result, nothing? I suppose this can be done but I have to ask why? Why do you need to micro-manage user work? If I were the user, I would quickly get annoyed by this.

Comment: Yes, me too, it's really annoying, client requirements. what can I do? no result no error.

Comment: This is a Navigation Form, not a Tab control? I hope you pointed out to client possibility of negative user experience.

Comment: Maybe I have to do that. Thanks

Comment: I am exploring code. What is navReports - the tab or form or subform container? LostFocus event does not have Cancel argument, at least not in Access2010. Your code will not compile. "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: If this can be done, will need someone smarter to figure out. I tried combination of GotFocus and LostFocus with DoCmd.BrowseTo and public variable and still doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: If client wants to micro-manage user navigation of forms, then Navigation Form or Tab control likely not best approach. Maybe use popup forms.

Comment: It would be huge work to re-arrange the tab to popup. It's quite unnecessary. I will definitely try to convince him.